# Set language for moth abbreviations

Tags: python, pandas

I have months specified as numbers from 1 to 12 in my `pandas` dataframe. By using `calendar.month_abbr` I convert them to words as follows:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

By default it's English.

Is it possible to specify a language?

Comment: "Is it possible to specify a language?" Yes, but you'd need to change the locale first, as per the docs: "An array that represents the abbreviated months of the year *in the current locale*" https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
    Month
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
10     11
11     12


In [30]: import locale

In [31]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de')
Out[31]: 'de'

In [32]: import calendar

In [33]: df['de'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
    Month   de
0       1  Jan
1       2  Feb
2       3  Mrz
3       4  Apr
4       5  Mai
5       6  Jun
6       7  Jul
7       8  Aug
8       9  Sep
9      10  Okt
10     11  Nov
11     12  Dez
```

Comment: I wonder why `'de'` was the first example to come to mind (-;

Comment: I get an error `Error: unsupported locale setting`.

Comment: Finally, this works for me `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_DK.UTF-8')`